# How to use left join in this context (If that is even the correct way to accomplish my task)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am confused how to complete this problem that i currently have infront of me. I am very new to SQL however, so I apologize if there is not much help from my side.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gv80l.png

These are my 2 tables. For info on the problem, for *incoming calls* a charge of 1 call unit/second is levied. For *outgoing calls* a charge of 500 call units is charged for the first 2 minutes of a call, then 2 units/second after that, for example a 3 minute outgoing call is (500+60*2) 620.

I want to have my output give me names, phone numbers, and then the total billed units. For example, based on the tables in the photo,

output would look like:

```
Geoffrey Chase 8052564516 363
Mollie Mcguire 9997156377 1288
```

Geoffrey Chase with phone number 8052564516 received 2 incoming calls of 264 and 99 seconds each. The billing for this is 363 call units in total.etc. Any ideas?

[Simplified example fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uWXtSmzromqtxKLpEDJCM3/0)

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not as images (or links to them.)

Comment: Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Please do not post links to images of code/data; instead post it as text formatted as code.

Comment: Geoffrey also got an outgoing call with 171 seconds, shouldn't this be included, too?

Answer (score 0):

Using the column names from the fiddle, I created a subquery that contains the charge per number and the I joined it with the customer details table. The charge table was created using a UNION to combine incoming charges with outgoing charges that are calculated differently.

```
SELECT
  customer.cname,
  SUM(charge_per_number.charge)
FROM cust_det AS customer
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
      inc_no AS phone_no
     ,duration AS charge
    FROM call_rec 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
       out_no AS phone_no
       ,CASE WHEN duration > 120 
             THEN 500+(duration-120)*2 
             ELSE 500 
       END  AS charge
    FROM call_rec 
) AS charge_per_number 
     ON charge_per_number.phone_no=customer.phone_no
GROUP BY customer.cname
```

Comment: Must be UNION ALL

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution: Two Derived Tables/CTEs to calculate the incoming/outgoing sums, which are both Left Joined to customer_detail:

```
SELECT
  customer.cname,
  COALESCE(incoming.charge, 0),
  COALESCE(outgoing.charge, 0),
  COALESCE(incoming.charge, 0) + COALESCE(outgoing.charge, 0)
FROM cust_det AS customer
LEFT JOIN
 (
    SELECT 
       inc_no AS phone_no
      ,duration AS charge
    FROM call_rec
    GROUP BY inc_no
 ) as incoming
ON incoming.phone_no=customer.phone_no
LEFT JOIN 
 (
    SELECT 
       out_no AS phone_no
      --500 call units is charged for the first 2 minutes of a call, then 2 units/second after that
      ,500 + greatest(duration-120,0) * 2 AS charge
    FROM call_rec 
 ) as outgoing
ON outgoing.phone_no=customer.phone_no
```

Answer (score 0):

The most recent versions of MySQL support `lateral` joins, which allows:

```
select cu.name, sum(charge)
from cust_det cu left join
     (call_rec cr cross join lateral
      (select cr.in_no as phone_no, cr.duration as charge union all
       select cr.out_no as phone_no, 500 + 2 * greatest(duration - 120, 0) 
     )
     on cu.phone_no = cr.phone_no
group by cu.name;
```